How can I select an International Keyboard after version 18 of the iPadOS?
I was using my iPad keyboard with the international layout, and everything was working properly. After I updated to version 18 of iPadOS, it stoped working and I cannot configure it again.
I want to be able to use accents like “ã” and “á” by just inputing the symbol and then the letter. For example “shift + ~”, followed by “a” yields “ã”.
I do not want the style of control / option / cmd + a, as it does not include all possible accents. And I do not want to hold down the “a” key, as it slow down typing.
How do I configure this on iPadOS 18 and later?

On the iPad, go to “Settings” > “Keyboards” > “Keyboards” and add all the languages you want.
Then go to “Settings” > “Keyboards” > “Hardware Keyboard”. There, for each of the available languages you can select the type of input. For your case with the “dead keys”, you can select “US International PC”
